# How can I convey this to CorpIT?

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-web-roles

My Azure web role can, using remote desktop, connect with a browser (IE) to google.com and to a DMZ server on our corporate network.

My web role cannot connect via HTTP GET (IE) to a non-DMZ box behind the firewall. My web role cannot ping this box either. My service is hosted in north/central, allegedly all published IP ranges of north/central have been granted access to the target IP by our CorpIT people. They claim they are seeing no traffic via their sniffer from my compute instance IP when I attempt to ping or HTTP GET against the target local IP.

CorpIT wants help from the Microsoft side but we have no Microsoft relationship. I'm convinced this is the outcome of months of slapdash thirdhand firewall rules applied to the target environment in question. What can I do to further elucidate this for CorpIT?

thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run a trace route or get a network trace from the Azure instance and see what you get back from where.  You could also create a support case with microsoft:

https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?&c1=501&gprid=14928&&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn

Comment: Don't worry about not having a "relationship" with MS, you're paying them for their services and the Azure support people will happily help you.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bet on using the IP ranges to make your applications work correctly. Windows Azure already provides you with some services that allow you to solve these types of issues:

- [Windows Azure Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433122.aspx): Allows you to create an IPSec secured connection between your servers and your hosted services. This means you won't need to add rules to the firewall for incoming traffic.
- [Windows Azure Service Bus Relay](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-relay/#what-is): Allows you to expose WCF services to the cloud without having to add rules to the firewall for incoming traffic. Choosing this option might add some extra work for you to do, you might need to create a WCF service if you don't already have one and change the code in your Web Role to connect to this WCF Service.